# PregMach with php GET method

Tags: php

I have a page test.php in which I have a list of names:

```
name1='992345'
name2='332345'
name3='558645'
name4='434544'
```

In another page `test1.php?id=name2` and the result should be:

> 332345

I've tried this PHP code:

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php")
$id = $_GET["id"];
;preg_match_all('/$id.=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match); 
$fid=$Match[1][0]; 
echo $fid; ?>
```

if the code is used like this

```
<?php 
    $Text=file_get_contents("test.php")
    ;preg_match_all('/name3=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match); 
    $fid=$Match[1][0]; 
    echo $fid; ?>
```

the result is good

> 558645

But i wanto be able to change the name of `'/name3=\'` from `;preg_match_all('/name3=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match)` with GET method like this if `test1.php?id=name4` the result wil bee `434544`.

Comment: `preg_match_all("/$id.='([^']+)'/",$Text,$Match); `

Comment: you may want to `urldecode($_GET['id']);` to remove encoded characters ie `+` and `preg_quote($id)` in case `id` contains regex characters like  . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$regex = "/".$id."=\'([^\']+)\'/";
preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
$fid=$Match[1][0]; 
echo $fid; ?>
```

This will work.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   $id = $_GET["id"];
   $regex = "/".$id."=\'([^\']+)\'/";
   preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
   $fid=$Match[1][0]; 
   echo $fid; 
} else {
   echo "There is no name selected.";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: `<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("http://portaltv.ro/STREAM.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];
preg_match_all("/$id='([^']+)'/",$Text,$Match); 
$fid=$Match[1][0]; 
echo $fid; ?>`

Comment: it works now ! with thw code i posted erlier!
it works with you code to. thanks.

Comment: now i have another problem if test1.php has no Get id element the php code echo the first contentent `122123` from name1='122123'
i need to be blank if test1.php has no get id element!

Comment: @PortaltvRomania Are you saying that if $_GET don't have id then it should print the name1 or is printing name1? please specify. I give give you solution.

Comment: test1.php?id=name2 works ok. but wen i enter the page with test1.php only, without id=name1 the php code prints the first name1 content.
i need that code to not print enithing. to be blank.

Comment: @PortaltvRomania I have edited the pots check it. this will not give you default name1 value.

Answer (score 1):

In `'`(single quote) the variable is treated as a text not as variable.

change this

```
preg_match_all('/$id.=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match);
```

to

```
preg_match_all("/$id=\'([^\']+)\'/",$Text,$Match);
```